# How do I convert HTML input to form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, input

I would like to turn this into a Rails `form_for`:

```
<input type="text" class="auto" data-a-sign="$ ">
```

I'm currently using HAML and my code looks like this:

```
= form_for @foto,:url => products_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|

  %p
    = f.label :price
    = f.text_field :price
  %p.button
    = f.submit
```

Comment: Why do you delete [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258789/rewriting-a-html-input-box-into-form-for) and then ask the same question again? If there was a problem with it, you should have edited it, not ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I had answered this same question a little while ago.  Anyway my answer was:

```
= text_field_tag "currency", nil, class: "auto", data: { a_sign: "$ " }
```

Comment: undefined method `text_field_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xb64b61b0>

Comment: Yeah, you had answered it, but Alain deleted [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258789/rewriting-a-html-input-box-into-form-for).

Comment: @AlainGoldman, the `text_field_tag` is a helper method.  I hope you are not using it with the "f" object.

Comment: i'm not but when i submit form i get a 'price' cant be blank

Comment: That's a separate issue, you probably have `presence` validation on `price` field in your `product` model.  Since the validation is a separate issue, I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: %p
= f.label :price
= text_field_tag "currency", nil, class: "auto", data: { a_sign: "$ " }

Comment: Oh boy, now I think I understand the question based on what you've posted.  Correct me if I didn't understand it.  Use the following: `%p
  = f.label :price
  = f.text_field :price, class: "auto", data: { a_sign: "$ "}`

Comment: solved it    = f.text_field :price, class: "auto", data: { a_sign: "$ " }

thanks